# When clicked, JS is not taking me to the correct href link it is assigned to

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, href

I have a dropdown menu that I want users to be able to click open, after it's clicked open they should be able to click a variable or anywhere within the variable box and take them to a new link not just the text. However, currently, when I click the text within the dropdown after it's opened, it is not taking me to any link and when I am clicking outside the text within the box, it is taking me to an undefined link. I have used this JS function before and it has worked and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here.

I specifically was checking if this code block was working by introducing a dummy html page under surface and precipitation as the variable 2m-Temperature

```js
                 document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-container-var ul li").forEach(d => {
                  d.addEventListener("click", e => {
                    const dropdown = e.target.closest(".dropdown-container-var ").querySelector("ul")
                    if(dropdown) {
                      dropdown.style.display = "block"
                      _ElementBlur(e.target, () => {
                        dropdown.style.display = "none"
                      })
                    }
                  })
                })
                document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-container-var").forEach(d => {
                  d.addEventListener("click", e => {
                    const dropdown = e.target.closest(".dropdown-container-var ").querySelector("ul")
                    if(dropdown) {
                      dropdown.style.display = "block"
                      _ElementBlur(e.target, () => {
                        dropdown.style.display = "none"
                      })
                    }
                  })
                })

                document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-container-var ul li").forEach(listItem => {
                  listItem.addEventListener("click", e => {
                    window.location.href = e.target.querySelector("a2").href
                  })
                })



                // Functions for getting a 'blur' event on an element
                const _ElementBlur = (el, f = false) => {
                  const ac = new AbortController()
                  document.body.addEventListener("click", _CheckBlur(el, f, ac), { signal: ac.signal })
                }

                const _CheckBlur = (el, f = false, ac) => {
                  return e => {
                    if(!document.elementsFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY).filter(efp => efp == el).length || !document.elementsFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY).length) {
                      if(f && typeof(f) == "function") f()
                      ac.abort()
                    }
                  }
                }
```

```css
    a3 {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;/* Change this to the desired color */
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
    }

    a2 {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;/* Change this to the desired color */
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
    }

    .dropdown-container-var {
      position: relative; /* create a positioning context for the list items */
      background-color: #333;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
    width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
        transition: background-color 0.2s;
        cursor: pointer;

        }

    .dropdown-container-var:hover { /* create a positioning context for the list items */
      background-color: #525252;
        transition: background-color 0.2s;
    }


    .dropdown-list-var {
      position: relative; /* position the list items absolutely */
     display: none; /* hide the list by default */

      list-style-type: none; /* remove the bullet points for the list items */
      padding: 0; /* remove the padding for the list */
      left: 0; /* position the list items at the left edge of the list */
      transition: border 0.2s; /* add a transition effect for the border */
      background-color: #b0b0b0;
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
    width: 600px;
        text-align: center;
        transition: background-color 0.2s;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .dropdown-list-var li:hover {
      background-color: #04AA6D;
        transition: background-color 0.2s;}/* change the background color of the list items 
    to green when they are hovered over */
    }
    .dropdown-list-var li {
      color: black; /* set the color of the list items to black */
        text-align: center;
        transition: background-color 0.2s;
    }
    p2 {
      margin: 0;
    }

    .dropdown-list-var {
      margin: 0; /* <-- add this to the existing CSS code*/
      /* the rest */
    }
    optgroup {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: black;
      width: 520px;
        cursor: default; 
    }
```

```html
    <div class="dropdown-container-var">
      <p2><a3 href="#" >Surface and Precipitation</a3></p2>
      <ul class="dropdown-list-var">
          <ul class = "optgroup">
          <optgroup label="Surface">
          </ul>
        <li><a2 href="dummylink.html">2m Temperature</a2></li>
        <li><a2 href="#">2m Dewpoint</a2></li>
        <li><a2 href="#">Mean Sea Level Pressure</a2></li>
          <li><a2 href="#">10m Wind</a2></li>
                <ul class = "optgroup">
          <optgroup label="Precipitation">
          </ul>
        <li><a2 vale="" href="#">6-hr Precipitation Type/Rate</a2></li>
        <li><a2 href="#">Categorical Precipitation Type</a2></li>
          <li><a2 href="#">6-hr Precipitation</a2></li>
          <li><a2 href="#">24-hr Precipitation</a2></li>
        <li><a2 href="#">Total Precipitation</a2></li>
                      <ul class = "optgroup">
          <optgroup label="Winter">
          </ul>
          <li><a2 href="#">Total Snowfall</a2></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-container-var">
      <p2><a3 href="#" >Upper-Air: Dynamics</a3></p2>
      <ul class="dropdown-list-var">
                <ul class = "optgroup">
          <optgroup label="Vorticity">
          </ul>
          <li><a2 href="#">500 hPa Height,Wind,Vorticity</a2></li>
        <li><a2 href="#">700 hPa Height,Wind,Vorticity</a2></li>
        <li><a2 href="#">850 hPa Height,Wind,Vorticity</a2></li>
                      <ul class = "optgroup">
          <optgroup label="Lift">
          </ul>
            <li><a2 href="#">700 hPa Frontogenesis/Temperature Advection</a2></li>
          <li><a2 href="#">700 hPa Omega</a2></li>
        <li><a2 href="#">850 hPa Frontogenesis/Temperature Advection</a2></li>
          <li><a2 href="#">850 hPa Omegan</a2></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-container-var">
      <p2><a3 href="#" >Upper-Air: Temperature,Wind</a3></p2>
      <ul class="dropdown-list-var">
                            <ul class = "optgroup">
          <optgroup label="Temperature">
          </ul>
          <li><a2 href="#">700 hPa Temperature, Height, Wind</a2></li>
        <li><a2 href="#">850 hPa Temperature, Height, Wind</a2></li>
        <li><a2 href="#">925 hPa Temperature, Height, Wind</a2></li>
            <ul class = "optgroup">
          <optgroup label="Wind">
          </ul>
        <li><a2 href="#">250 hPa Height, Wind</a2></li>
        <li><a2 href="#">850 hPa Height, Wind</a2></li>
                <ul class = "optgroup">
          <optgroup label="Anomaly">
          </ul>
          <li><a2 href="#">500 hPa Height Anomaly</a2></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change line 27 of your JavaScript code to

```
window.location.href = e.target.attributes.href.value;
```

The element you are catching at that point (e.target) is a2 itself. Running query selector on it searches for an `a2` tag in its descendants and cannot find anything. Btw, some friendly suggestions: avoid using non-standard tags such as `a2` and make use of `debugger` statement to see what you have at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this javascript code.
try to use e.target.getAttribute("href")

```js
 document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-container-var ul li").forEach(d => {
                  d.addEventListener("click", e => {
                    const dropdown = e.target.closest(".dropdown-container-var ").querySelector("ul")
                    if(dropdown) {
                      dropdown.style.display = "block"
                      _ElementBlur(e.target, () => {
                        dropdown.style.display = "none"
                      })
                    }
                  })
                })
                document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-container-var").forEach(d => {
                  d.addEventListener("click", e => {
                    const dropdown = e.target.closest(".dropdown-container-var ").querySelector("ul")
                    if(dropdown) {
                      dropdown.style.display = "block"
                      _ElementBlur(e.target, () => {
                        dropdown.style.display = "none"
                      })
                    }
                  })
                })

                document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-container-var ul li").forEach(listItem => {
                  listItem.addEventListener("click", e => {
                    var url = e.target.getAttribute("href")
                    window.open(url, '_blank');
                  })
                })



                // Functions for getting a 'blur' event on an element
                const _ElementBlur = (el, f = false) => {
                  const ac = new AbortController()
                  document.body.addEventListener("click", _CheckBlur(el, f, ac), { signal: ac.signal })
                }

                const _CheckBlur = (el, f = false, ac) => {
                  return e => {
                    if(!document.elementsFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY).filter(efp => efp == el).length || !document.elementsFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY).length) {
                      if(f && typeof(f) == "function") f()
                      ac.abort()
                    }
                  }
                }
```

```css
 a3 {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;/* Change this to the desired color */
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
    }

    a2 {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;/* Change this to the desired color */
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
    }

    .dropdown-container-var {
      position: relative; /* create a positioning context for the list items */
      background-color: #333;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
    width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
        transition: background-color 0.2s;
        cursor: pointer;

        }

    .dropdown-container-var:hover { /* create a positioning context for the list items */
      background-color: #525252;
        transition: background-color 0.2s;
    }


    .dropdown-list-var {
      position: relative; /* position the list items absolutely */
     display: none; /* hide the list by default */

      list-style-type: none; /* remove the bullet points for the list items */
      padding: 0; /* remove the padding for the list */
      left: 0; /* position the list items at the left edge of the list */
      transition: border 0.2s; /* add a transition effect for the border */
      background-color: #b0b0b0;
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
    width: 600px;
        text-align: center;
        transition: background-color 0.2s;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .dropdown-list-var li:hover {
      background-color: #04AA6D;
        transition: background-color 0.2s;}/* change the background color of the list items 
    to green when they are hovered over */
    }
    .dropdown-list-var li {
      color: black; /* set the color of the list items to black */
        text-align: center;
        transition: background-color 0.2s;
    }
    p2 {
      margin: 0;
    }

    .dropdown-list-var {
      margin: 0; /* <-- add this to the existing CSS code*/
      /* the rest */
    }
    optgroup {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: black;
      width: 520px;
        cursor: default; 
    }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-container-var">
      <p2><a3 href="#" >Surface and Precipitation</a3></p2>
      <ul class="dropdown-list-var">
          <ul class = "optgroup">
          <optgroup label="Surface">
          </ul>
        <li><a2 href="https://dummylink.html">2m Temperature</a2></li>
        <li><a2 href="#">2m Dewpoint</a2></li>
        <li><a2 href="#">Mean Sea Level Pressure</a2></li>
          <li><a2 href="#">10m Wind</a2></li>
                <ul class = "optgroup">
          <optgroup label="Precipitation">
          </ul>
        <li><a2 vale="" href="#">6-hr Precipitation Type/Rate</a2></li>
        <li><a2 href="#">Categorical Precipitation Type</a2></li>
          <li><a2 href="#">6-hr Precipitation</a2></li>
          <li><a2 href="#">24-hr Precipitation</a2></li>
        <li><a2 href="#">Total Precipitation</a2></li>
                      <ul class = "optgroup">
          <optgroup label="Winter">
          </ul>
          <li><a2 href="#">Total Snowfall</a2></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-container-var">
      <p2><a3 href="#" >Upper-Air: Dynamics</a3></p2>
      <ul class="dropdown-list-var">
                <ul class = "optgroup">
          <optgroup label="Vorticity">
          </ul>
          <li><a2 href="#">500 hPa Height,Wind,Vorticity</a2></li>
        <li><a2 href="#">700 hPa Height,Wind,Vorticity</a2></li>
        <li><a2 href="#">850 hPa Height,Wind,Vorticity</a2></li>
                      <ul class = "optgroup">
          <optgroup label="Lift">
          </ul>
            <li><a2 href="#">700 hPa Frontogenesis/Temperature Advection</a2></li>
          <li><a2 href="#">700 hPa Omega</a2></li>
        <li><a2 href="#">850 hPa Frontogenesis/Temperature Advection</a2></li>
          <li><a2 href="#">850 hPa Omegan</a2></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-container-var">
      <p2><a3 href="#" >Upper-Air: Temperature,Wind</a3></p2>
      <ul class="dropdown-list-var">
                            <ul class = "optgroup">
          <optgroup label="Temperature">
          </ul>
          <li><a2 href="#">700 hPa Temperature, Height, Wind</a2></li>
        <li><a2 href="#">850 hPa Temperature, Height, Wind</a2></li>
        <li><a2 href="#">925 hPa Temperature, Height, Wind</a2></li>
            <ul class = "optgroup">
          <optgroup label="Wind">
          </ul>
        <li><a2 href="#">250 hPa Height, Wind</a2></li>
        <li><a2 href="#">850 hPa Height, Wind</a2></li>
                <ul class = "optgroup">
          <optgroup label="Anomaly">
          </ul>
          <li><a2 href="#">500 hPa Height Anomaly</a2></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: this still doesn't work, when I click on an area just outside the text when the box is open it sends me to a "null" link. I want the box to send me to the same href that the text does if possible. Thank you!

Comment: It worked for me. did you try to run it on this platform? if you test it on codepen or individual file, it would works.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the issue might be with the line

```js
window.location.href = e.target.querySelector("a2").href;
```

Instead of calling `querySelector`, you should be calling `getAttribute` to get the value of the `href` attribute of the `a2` element. Also, the `a2` element should be a child of the `li` element that you are adding the click event listener to, so you should be using

```js
e.target.querySelector("a2").getAttribute("href");
```

instead.

```js
window.location.href = e.target.querySelector("a2").href
```

should be:

```js
window.location.href = e.target.querySelector("a2").getAttribute("href")
```